# SQL 2012 -> SQL 2014 upgrade failure

Tags: sql-server

I did a SQL 2012 to SQL 2014 upgrade using the upgrade wizard.

The install failed for the DB, Full-Text, Replication, AS and SSRS components, and the error reported was due to a backup location no longer existing. I've fixed the issue by changing the default backup location in the registry (HKLM\Software\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.\MSSQLServer\BackupDirectory).

Even though the install of the above components failed, the installation of the common components (Management Tools, Integration Services, Sql Browser, Sql Writer) succeeded.

However, when running the install again and get to the Select Features step, I'm presented with this :

[image: Select Feature Step Error]

and I'm unable to continue.

From the report of the previous setup, I've found this :

> The upgrade process for SQL Server failed. To continue the upgrade process, use the following information to resolve the error. Next, uninstall SQL Server by using this command line: setup /q /action=uninstall /instanceid=MyInstance /features=RS,SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT,REPLICATION. Then, run SQL Server Setup again.

Is there a way to get setup to proceed without having to uninstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did the uninstall since its in a non-prod environment... Since you run the SQL 2014 uninstaller, I assume it removes the SQL 2014 installed components for your instance. After the uninstall, my SQL 2012 instance was still accessible.

The SQL 2014 installer continued normally after the uninstall.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful information for me as it wasn't clear that only the 2014 components were going to be removed.